# Parametrized tests with parametrized SetUp()/TearDown()

Tags: c++, googletest, fixtures

I have a test fixture that shares most of the test code. The variations are mostly from a parameter value. I would like to create `SetUp()` / `TearDown()` for them, but they (obviously) can't be called with a parameter.
What would the best strategy to use `SetUp()` / `TearDown()` mechanisms while avoiding code duplication?

This is my original code :

```
class FileToolsTest : public testing::Test
{
   protected:

   void TestReadAndWrite(const wstring& filename, const wstring& content)
   {
      FileTools::RemoveFile(filename);

      // Test code there

      ok = FileTools::RemoveFile(filename);
      ASSERT_EQ(true, ok);
   }
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, ReadAndWrite_case1)
{
   const wstring testFilename = L"testfile";
   const wstring testContent = L"This\nis\ndummy\ndata";
   TestReadAndWrite(testFilename, testContent);
}

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, ReadAndWrite_case2)
{
   const wstring testFilename = L"testfíle";
   const wstring testContent = L"This\nis\ndummy\n\nuníc@de datã éééé";
   TestReadAndWrite(testFilename, testContent);
}

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, Write_case3)
{
   const wstring testFilename = L"Micka\x00ebl/fileWithUnicodeFolderInPath2.txt";

   if (FileTools::FileExists(testFilename))
   {
      const bool ok = FileTools::RemoveFile(testFilename);
      ASSERT_TRUE(ok);
   }

   // Test code there

   FileTools::RemoveFile(testFilename);
}
```

As you can see, `::RemoveFile()` is duplicated between `TestReadAndWrite()` and Write_case3(), both at test start and test end.

Comment: I wouldn't really call it "duplicate code" based on this snippet (I'm not a fan of refactoring for the sake of refactoring). If there's more to that code and you always need to clean up the file, you could pass filename as class member and read it in `TearDown()`. Or go full boilerplate mode and do parameterized tests or even separate test fixtures for each test.

Comment: You have used the very correct words "parameterized tests". Look at [Value-Parameterized Tests](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#value-parameterized-tests)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen This is not a "real" problem in the sense that there is little code involved in the duplication. Still, it bothers me to have to "manually" replicate the initialization and finalization code for all cases

Comment: @273K Thank you for your comment. This is indeed a nice way to do it, but as far as I see SetUp() and TearDown() can't use the parameters. What I am specially interested in is using a parametrized SetUp().
Any more ideas?

Comment: They could - `const auto &param = GetParam();`

Comment: side note: well behaving unit test should not save anything on disk. This makes test slow and fragile. Good practice is to operate on `std::stream &` and feed `std::stringstream` when testing such code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example of Value-Parameterized Test.

```
#include <string>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct FileTools {
  static bool RemoveFile(const std::wstring&);
};

struct FileToolsTestParam {
  const std::wstring testFilename;
  const std::wstring testContent;
} kFileToolsTestParam[] = {
  {
   L"testfile",
   L"This\nis\ndummy\ndata"
  },
  {
   L"testfíle",
   L"This\nis\ndummy\n\nuníc@de datã éééé"
  }
};

class FileToolsTest : public testing::TestWithParam<FileToolsTestParam> {
  protected:
   void SetUp() override {
     const auto& param = GetParam();
     FileTools::RemoveFile(param.testFilename);
   }
   void TearDown() override {
     const auto& param = GetParam();
     const bool ok = FileTools::RemoveFile(param.testContent);
     ASSERT_EQ(true, ok);
   }
};

INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P(FileTools, FileToolsTest, testing::ValuesIn(kFileToolsTestParam));

TEST_P(FileToolsTest, ReadAndWrite) {
  // Test code there
}
```

Comment: Right, I tried it before but I had a compilation error with it. Just realized now it wasn't because of parameter usage in SetUp(), it was because there was still a TEST_F using this class.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can make your parameters members of your test fixture class and still keep your tests' readability:

```
class FileToolsTest : public testing::Test {
 protected:

  void TearDown() override {
    const bool ok = FileTools::RemoveFile(testFilename_);
    ASSERT_EQ(true, ok);
  }

  void TestReadAndWrite() {
    FileTools::RemoveFile(testFilename_);
    // Test code there
  }

  // Test parameters:
  wstring testFilename_;
  wstring testContent_;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, ReadAndWrite_case1) {
  testFilename_ = L"testfile";
  testContent_ = L"This\nis\ndummy\ndata";
  TestReadAndWrite();
}

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, ReadAndWrite_case2) {
  testFilename_ = L"testfíle";
  testContent_ = L"This\nis\ndummy\n\nuníc@de datã éééé";
  TestReadAndWrite();
}

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, Write_case3) {
  testFilename_ = L"Micka\x00ebl/fileWithUnicodeFolderInPath2.txt";

  if (FileTools::FileExists(testFilename_)) {
    const bool ok = FileTools::RemoveFile(testFilename_);
    ASSERT_TRUE(ok);
  }

  // Test code there
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/5q69rrEWc

You can even overload and make your `TestReadAndWrite` parameterized:

```
class FileToolsTest : public testing::Test {
 protected:

  void TearDown() override {
    const bool ok = FileTools::RemoveFile(testFilename_);
    ASSERT_EQ(true, ok);
  }

  void TestReadAndWrite() {
    FileTools::RemoveFile(testFilename_);
    // Test code there
  }

   void TestReadAndWrite(wstring testFilename, wstring testContent) {
    testFilename_ = testFilename;
    testContent_ = testContent;
    TestReadAndWrite();
  }

  // Test parameters:
  wstring testFilename_;
  wstring testContent_;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, ReadAndWrite_case1) {
  TestReadAndWrite(/*testFilename=*/ L"testfile", 
                   /*testContent=*/ L"This\nis\ndummy\ndata");
}

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, ReadAndWrite_case2) {
   TestReadAndWrite(/*testFilename=*/  L"testfíle", 
                    /*testContent=*/ L"This\nis\ndummy\n\nuníc@de datã éééé");
}

TEST_F(FileToolsTest, Write_case3) {
  testFilename_ = L"Micka\x00ebl/fileWithUnicodeFolderInPath2.txt";

  if (FileTools::FileExists(testFilename_)) {
    const bool ok = FileTools::RemoveFile(testFilename_);
    ASSERT_TRUE(ok);
  }

  // Test code there
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/dzs9rYvqj

Comment: this is as clunky as original solution.

Comment: @MarekR Why is that?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it does not work as I intended : I can't use the parameter in SetUp() as it is being set after.